# Weird messages when using sudo

Tags: 14.04, command-line, sudo

Whenever I run a `sudo` command in the terminal, this happens:

```
arun@arun-GP70-2OD:~$ sudo apt-get update
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/README is world writable
sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700
 [sudo] password for arun:
```

The `sudo` commands still work (I think so, although the only one I have tested is `sudo apt-get`).

What are these strange messages before I get asked for the password? Is there any big problem here? Should I do something about this? Or can I just leave it like this and continue using my system?

Comment: Well, did you check the permission on /etc/sudoers.d/README file as the error suggested ?

Comment: I'd be concerned about overall system security/stability at this point, as clearly something has happened to screw up permissions. It may be the relatively safe option of a filesystem becoming corrupt, or something more insidious.

Comment: @Phil Lello Yes, I formated my drive and did a clean install. More details in the comments under the accepted answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The messages are self explanatory.

By design `sudo` related files and libraries should only be readable (and writable if needed) by `root`.

The directory `/var/lib/sudo` contains individual user's `sudo` related data, which could be easily read/modified if a non-root user have sufficient permission, which is of course a security issue.

The file `/etc/sudoers.d/README` contains info regarding implementation of `sudo`. Imagine a rogue user edit the file and add false info (and you follow that).

So, in a nutshell, fix the permissions:

```
sudo chmod 0400 /etc/sudoers.d/README
sudo chmod -R 0700 /var/lib/sudo  ## Recursively
```

And of course make sure the owner is `root` (and group `root`).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37617/discussion-on-answer-by-heemayl-weird-messages-when-using-sudo).

Comment: @heemayl Maybe it's worth adding to the answer that whatever caused a problem like this might possibly have caused other security problems as well? I, fearing this, formated my drive and did a clean install.